# Managing custom theme translations file

Tags: 8, theming, i18n-l10n

How to add a translation file to a custom theme?

I did

**my_theme.info.yml**

```
'interface translation project': my_theme
'interface translation server pattern': themes/my_theme/translations/my_theme-%language.po
```

**twig template:**

```
 {% trans %}
  status
{% endtrans %}

{{ 'status'|t }}
```

**/my_theme/translations/my_theme-fr.po:**

```
msgid "status"
msgstr "statut"

msgid "statut"
msgstr "status"
```

followed by a

```
drush cr
```

The output is not translated when I am on the *fr* page (the default language being english).

Answer (score 1):

The .po file is not imported by being placed in the themes directory, you need to import it. To do that go here:

`Home > Administration > Configuration > Region and Language > Import`

Comment: in /admin/config/regional/translate/import it says : "Les fichiers de traduction sont automatiquement téléchargés et importés quand des langues sont ajoutées, ou quand des modules ou thèmes sont activés.". This does not work when i activate the theme

Comment: @Jdrupal, turns out *you can* import the PO from your theme or module, I didn't know either when I replied initially. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21locale.api.php/group/interface_translation_properties/8.6.x

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation seems to follow the guidelines on the [locale API documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21locale.api.php/group/interface_translation_properties/8.6.x), but nevertheless, it wasn't working for me either.

What worked for me was implementing [hook_locale_translation_projects_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21locale.api.php/function/hook_locale_translation_projects_alter) **on a module**:

```
function mymodule_locale_translation_projects_alter(&$projects) {
  $projects['my_theme'] = array(
    'info' => array(
      'interface translation server pattern' => 'themes/custom/my_theme/translations/my_theme-%language.po',
    ),
  );
}
```

I tested by enabling the module first, then enabling adding the language via drush command:

```
drush language-add fr
```

This is my PO file, Drupal seems to require a heading section:

```
# French translation of Drush Site-Install
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PROJECT VERSION\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2018-10-11 16:30+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2018-10-11 16:30+0000\n"
"Last-Translator: NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1);\n"

msgid "status"
msgstr "statut"

msgid "statut"
msgstr "status"
```

Without the header, it was skipping the first translation and I was getting this error:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /batch?id=14&op=do_nojs&op=do
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in Drupal\Component\Gettext\PoHeader->parseHeader() (line 257 of /app/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Gettext/PoHeader.php). => Array ...
```

Comment: in /admin/config/regional/translate/import it says : "Les fichiers de traduction sont automatiquement téléchargés et importés quand des langues sont ajoutées, ou quand des modules ou thèmes sont activés.". This does not work when i activate the theme

Comment: i have managed to set the automatic import of custom module po files on activation but not theme. are you sure it has to be manual?

Comment: I was looking a bit more into this, I think I am wrong and you can actually attach your translations to a module or theme, let me just update my answer. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21locale.api.php/group/interface_translation_properties/8.6.x

Comment: thanks but my info.yml properties above does not work

Comment: also manually import of previsouly imported and modified po files do not override the previous translation !?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to what **@Cesar Moore** said and executing `drush locale:check` then `drush locale:update` and `drush cr`, my translation file is now working for my custom theme too :)

FYI : my PO file is in a custom module folder.

More refs :

- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21locale.api.php/group/interface_translation_properties/8.6.x
- http://ymbra.com/blog/provide-interface-translations-custom-modules-drupal-8